# Using or clause with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Based on the following I'd like to query albums based on an `artist` and their `artist_credit`. The `artist_credit` association is polymorphic and can belong to a release or track. This prevents me doing a HMT. I can grab albums from the track side by doing an includes in my query as so:

```
Album.includes(tracks: :artist_credits).where(artist_credits: { id: artist_id })
```

But what I'd like to do is get ahold of both tracks **AND** releases. I thought of using an `or` clause but get this error:

```
ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:includes])
```

When attempting this:

```
Album.includes([tracks: :artist_credits, releases: :artist_credits]).where(artist_credits: { id: artist_id }).or(where(artist_credits: { id: artist_id }))
```

How can I get this to work? Any better way to do this?

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :releases, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :album_artists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: :album_artists
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_credits, as: :creditable, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :album
end

class Release < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_credits, as: :creditable, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :album
end

class ArtistCredit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :creditable, polymorphic: true # release or track
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
   scope :accredited_artist, ->(artist_id) {
      includes([tracks: :artist_credits, releases: :artist_credits])
       .where(id: 
         where(
           id: Track.accredited_artist(artist_id).select(:album_id)
         ).or(
           where(
             id: Release.accredited_artist(artist_id).select(:album_id)
           )
         )
       )
   }
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
   scope :accredited_artist, ->(artist_id) {
     joins(:artist_credits).where(artist_credits: { id: artist_id })
   }
end

class Release < ApplicationRecord
   scope :accredited_artist, ->(artist_id) {
     joins(:artist_credits).where(artist_credits: { id: artist_id })
   }
end
```

In theory this should result in a query that looks akin to

```
SELECT 
  albums.* 
FROM 
  albums
WHERE 
  albums.id IN (
     SELECT 
        albums.id
     FROM 
        albums
     WHERE
        albums.id IN ( 
          SELECT 
             tracks.album_id
          FROM 
             tracks
             INNER JOIN artist_credits ON [whatever your join is here] 
          WHERE 
             artist_credits.artist_id = [ID]) OR 
         albums.id IN ( 
          SELECT 
             releases.album_id
          FROM 
             releases
             INNER JOIN artist_credits ON [whatever your join is here] 
          WHERE 
             artist_credits.artist_id = [ID])
  )
```

Comment: Would using `select` in this case be somewhat of performance issue?

Comment: @CarlEdwards not sure I understand the question. The main issue is that you want to use includes and the native rails `or` condition.

Comment: I may be confusing select in the context of where.

Comment: @CarlEdwards `select` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` is specifying the columns to SELECT in the SQL statement. This is different from `Array#select` which would be iterative and require a block. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks for clarifying.